# Delphi mswinsck.ocx issue

Tags: class, delphi, 32bit-64bit, ocx

I have applications using 'mswinsck.ocx' file for windows messages.
My 'mswinsck.ocx' file is registered from 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64' folder.

All 32bit applications are working fine with this ocx file.

Now I am migrating my Delphi applications from 32bit to 64bit.

Should I require 64bit ocx file to run 64 bit exes?
I downloaded one and tried to register from system32 folder but got following error message:

[image]

I do not have code files of ocx file.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to continue using this library you will need a 64 bit version of it. If you cannot obtain a 64 bit version of the OCX there is little you can do. You may be compelled to replace this component.

Comment: Thank you David.
I cannot compile this ocx for 64bit because I have only one pas file(tlb)..no ridl file with me..

Comment: I think you will need to replace it, unless you can find the original vendor and obtain a 64 bit version. Based on the name, perhaps you just need to switch to Indy or similar.

Comment: Ok sure, I tried to download 64bit version of it.(din get proper link)  but it did not work out.

Comment: AFAIK, `mswinsck.ocx` is a legacy API, there is only a 32bit version of it, no 64bit version. The real question is, why are you using this API at all? WinSock is a native Win32 DLL-based API available in 32bit and 64bit versions, there is no good reason at all to use an ActiveX wrapper for it in native development environments, like Delphi. The main purpose of `mswinsck.ocx` is to provide socket access to scripting environments, like VBA. You really should re-write the app to use WinSock properly, or at least a native Delphi wrapper library for it, like Indy, ICS, etc.